# How to override GWT default style clean.css?

Tags: css, gwt

I want to use the **clean.css** style for my webapp but of course I want to override a few things for the purpose of customization. The problem is that my approach is not working. I have added these:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

to **mystyle.css** and included it into my **index.html** file.

The problem is that the styles are only getting overriden if I set `!important` to the attributes:

```
body {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

This is not practical as you can imagine. What do I have to do to be able to override the default styles from **clean.css**?

This is the **module.gwt.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean" />

  <source path="" />

  <entry-point class="com.mahlzeit.web.App" />

  <!-- Only support recent browsers -->
  <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie10,gecko1_8,safari" />
</module>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can for example remove the `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean" />` part and get the clean.css from [the gwt repo](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/theme/clean/public/gwt/clean/clean.css?r=9831). You can copy the entire content to your mystyle.css and modify the parts the you want overriden.

Comment: No need to get it from the repo - there should be a copy in your `/war/<yourprojectname>/gwt/<theme>` folder.